VMware-Player download not working
vmware website says timeout immediatly after clicking download player.. any idea to do it a different way. Got workstation bundle file, will that work??? Many Thanks ConvertOne

An Error 522 means that the request was able to connect to your web server, but that the request didn't finish. The most likely cause is that something on your server is hogging resources. Additional troubleshooting information here.
